# Fatal error: blenc_compile: Module php_blenc was expired. Please buy a new license key or disable the module. in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, xampp, php-5.5, blenc

When i run blenc encrypted file it gives error:

> Fatal error: blenc_compile: Module php_blenc was expired. Please buy a new license key or disable the module. in Unknown on line 0

These Steps i'm followed for **blenc** usage:

1. I installed latest version of blenc from [blenc-1.1.4b](http://pecl.php.net/package/BLENC/1.1.4b/windows) in **xampp**
2. then created a file *encoder.php* with content:

   `$source_code = file_get_contents("testcode.php");
   $redistributable_key = blenc_encrypt($source_code, "encrypt.php");
   $key_file = ini_get('blenc.key_file'); 
   file_put_contents($key_file, $redistributable_key . "\n", FILE_APPEND);`
3. then created a file *testcode.php* with content:

   `echo "hello";`
4. then i encoded the file named as *testcode.php* to *encrypt.php*.

And While run it, I got error given above.

Comment: _Please buy a new license key_

Comment: sir it's a opensource project.

Comment: i builded extension manually this error solved but another error occurred:
**Fatal error: blenc_compile: Validation of script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/test/encoded.php' failed, cannot execute. in Unknown on line 0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*php_blenc* need an absolute path for key_file like this in `php.ini`:

```
blenc.key_file = "d:/php/blenckeys"
```

and for license key error build *blenc* yourself and in source files `blenc_protect.h`

```
...

#define BLENC_PROTECT_EXPIRE "99-99-9999"

...
```

replace with

```
...

#define BLENC_PROTECT_EXPIRE "01-01-9999"

...
```

Comment: Hello Ameer, Can you please let me know how I can build blenc from source, I searched in google and tried but unable to do it. If possible can you please share dll with me which has valid expiry.