# create php extension from souce - php_blenc was expired

Tags: php, wampserver, php-extension, blenc

I want to encrypt my php source code for that I want to use php blenc, I have successfully implemented the encryption but when i run that php code it gives me following error.

```
Fatal error: blenc_compile: Module php_blenc was expired. Please buy a new license key or disable the module. in Unknown on line 0
```

So to resolve this I looked in google and found that fro m the source code i need to increase expiry and rebuild dll. I tried building dll but unable to doit.

If anyone have working dll for this please let me know, share the link from which i can create it for php 5.5.30

Instruction/permission is given on following page to use source code.

```
 php.net/manual/en/blenc.installation.php
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105962/fatal-error-blenc-compile-module-php-blenc-was-expired-please-buy-a-new-licen

Comment: What about doing what it says? `Please buy a new license key`

Comment: Thanks for reply, @rahul_m I did looked into that link and as it says i tried to build from source code but unable to do it. In same post you will find my comment on how to build it.

Comment: @MarkBaker, Its open source so we don't need to pay for it.

Comment: Open source means you can look at the source code. That doesn't mean it's free.

Comment: Downvoted.  At the least this is dishonest.  At most illegal.

Comment: @Narf Can you please let me know from where i can buy this??

Comment: @tjfo Did you even researched about what I am asking? Before commenting please get some knowledge. I tried to find out the valid dll even paid but it's not available.

Comment: @Satish I can't. I don't know if blenc is free or not. I just pointed out that "open source" isn't a synonym for "free".

Comment: @satish As the person asking the question it is your responsibility to provide relevant information needed to answer your question.  If you are aware that changing an expiration date and re-compiling a .dll is acceptable behavior to the company or person that provided this software, you should include that information in the question.  Otherwise, it just looks like you are trying to get this community to help you do something that is wrong.

Comment: @satish If you update the question with a resource showing that this is not an unethical thing to do, I will be happy to remove my downvote.

Comment: @tjfo this is the link where they have even shown how to do it. I think this is enough for you. https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: @Narf this is abstract from wiki about open source "Open-source software (OSS) is computer software with its source code made available with a license in which the copyright holder provides the rights to study, change, and distribute the software to anyone and for any purpose." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software

Comment: @Satish Well, believe it or not - Wikipedia can be wrong.

Comment: @Narf this is oxford dictionaries definition https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/open-source Sorry but this is not about being right or wrong, i just want to send message that if you don't know problem and still want to answer please research about it and than comment or provide you view, Thanks

Comment: @Satish And that Oxford dictionary definition talks about the *code* not its usage. There's a difference between looking at code and using it, and I can find just as many sources supporting my claim. I never said that I know what your problem is; I said that "open source" doesn't mean "free", and this *may* be the case that this is something that you're missing, in case BLENC does require you to buy a license (again I don't know if that's the case). We're getting too chatty here, so if you just refuse to believe me - so be it, your problem.

Comment: @Satish  That link was actually not what I was looking for so I did some research on my own.  It appears that setting the expiration date of the module is actually a feature of some sort.  I'm not sure why the "purchase" statement appears.  I can't remove my downvote unless you edit the question, so if you could add this link to the question I will remove my downvote: http://php.net/manual/en/blenc.installation.php

On this page it says: "It's strongly recommended to install BLENC from sources without 'pecl' command."  I'm not sure what that means but I will research when I have more time.

Comment: Another thought you may have already tried (if so please update question with this info as well).  Contact the maintainers listed on the official BLENC pecl listing (https://pecl.php.net/package/BLENC)

Comment: This is the best resource I've found on how to do what you are asking: https://www.sitepoint.com/compiling-php-from-source-on-windows/.  I haven't had time to try it myself.

Comment: @tjfo I have added the link you asked, thanks to all for reply and comment. I finally successfully created dll by compiling php and than source code of blenc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed steps give in this link and made dll successfully.

In this link they have given how to compile extension available in PECL web site.

```
https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild
```

Answer (score 1):

Consolidating an Answer for Posterity. If one of the helpful original commenters wants to post an answer I will upvote them, but if another user runs into this issue, it's hard to find the answer without... Well.. An answer.

The crux is that this error referencing a "purchase" is misleading. In order to avoid it, ensure you are carefully following installation instructions and building from source.

PHP Blenc, [according to its license](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/php/blenc.git;a=blob;f=LICENSE;h=e2f57fd1c0a0c0ba168315c8d51b499255845870;hb=HEAD), is open source ***and*** free, as it is under the [PHP License](http://www.php.net/license/).

> - PHP 4, PHP 5 and PHP 7 are distributed under the PHP License v3.01, copyright (c) the PHP Group.
>
>   - This is an Open Source license, certified by the Open Source Initiative.
>   - The PHP license is a BSD-style license which does not have the "copyleft" restrictions associated with GPL.

Please note that this is an old release, from 2013. It may not work on newer versions of PHP.

Evidently, this has been solved in the comments section of the answer above. The OP also added the relevant link from PHP, that should be followed closely [php.net/manual/en/blenc.installation.php](http://%20php.net/manual/en/blenc.installation.php).

Answer (score 0):

PHP BLENC has supports expiration time for the modules built upon it. If you develop your extension, make sure you specify the right expiration time within the source code and re-compile. Setting expiration date lets BLENC module to decide whether, target system will decrypt or not at particular date. All the configurations are stored header file blenc_protect.h